# What is a good strategy for iterative kernels with reads across workgroups?

Tags: kernel, iteration, opencl

I have an iterative process coded in a kernel. The process involves updates on different positions of a global buffer.

As I can't sync among different workgroups, the only strategy I can think of is queuing a kernel call for each iteration, and check the end condition from the host (queue iteration, queue buffer read to check the condition, queue iteration if needed, etc...)

Is there any better strategy to follow?

Comment: That's the usual strategy to get device-wide synchronization, and, as far as I'm aware of, the only correct one. Kernel calls are very cheap anyway. But please post your code (or at least pseudo-code) to make your question more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

A very good strategy (already proved myself), is to use extra memory, a double buffering method. It is fast, and easy to implement.

Each iteration you read from a given location (buffer1), and write to a different one (buffer2).
After the kernel iteration has finished, you swap buffer1 and buffer2. If you need it, "clean" the buffer that is going to receive the data (buffer1 this time). And continue.

In order to check the result from the CPU, you can queue an async readBuffer. So you are reading the content of buffer1, while the kernel is running on the same data. Ensuring the GPU is always busy.